# javascript treating special characters as utf characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, utf-8, ascii, utf

My subject line might not be that great to explain my problem but a screenshot will.

[image]

The screenshot contains 2 screens. The right one is the JS editor where I have written the actual code to replace the special character to " ' ".
On the left is the what I am seeing in the chrome browser.

**Is it possible to replace the special characters through JS similar to the way I am trying?**

My main problem is I am calling a ashx handler using ajax call through javascript.
This handler is returning me the special characters.
I have checked that I have the following code in my master page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Have also tried the following but in vain

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am now in the process of updating my SQL Server 2008 fields as per the following posts but I am not very sure if this will solve the problem.

[ASP.NET special character problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686391/asp-net-special-character-problem)

[Classic ASP gremlims, getting a Â inserted into text whenever an HTML special character is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350429/classic-asp-gremlims-getting-a-%C3%82-inserted-into-text-whenever-an-html-special-ch)

Help which involves Javascript will be preferable, if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really surprising in stackoverflow for a question with just 9 views and no answers.

Anyways found a relevant post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598786/how-to-replace-non-printable-unicode-characters-javascript) which helped solve my problem.

So, wrote something to the following (like a regex) to get the issue resolved.

```
var modTitle = article.Title.replace(/[â€“]/gi, '-');
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very simple approach to remove all special characters. Suppose to work even with old deprecated versions of browsers. Hope helps.

`var modTitle = article.Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');`

Best regards,
Dimitar